# Write the cookie in the model method or in the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, cookies

A controller method calls upon a model method to generate a token. Inside the controller method the generated token is also saved in a cookie: `cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token`.

Would it not be better to include this last line in the model method that creates the token? It is DRYer since I have more than 1 controller with this same behaviour (using the same model method). And the risk that I would forget these cookies lines is lower. Or is it not possible to execute this command in a model method?

**Update:** I think it's not possible to do this in a model method because there it's not known to which user/computer to write the cookie to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Models should have no knowledge about concepts like a user's cookie. It's really a controller thing.

If you're using the line across different controllers, you could move it into the `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def store_remember_token(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end
end
```

And then reuse it in your controllers:

```
class SomethingsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = # ...
    store_remember_token(@user)
  end
end
```